# Get Value of range slider on change yii2

Tags: yii2

I am working with Range slider in **YII 2.0** using [this link](http://demos.krajee.com/slider).

I am performing search using this range slider in form . On submit of form data I am getting the post data of range slider, **But** I want to get the value of range slider on change of slider so I can use it in jQuery and AJAX search.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the event of change in javascript or write the correct function in:

```
 pluginEvents[
 .....

"slide" => "function() { sendYourValueToServer(); }",
```